# Downloading Rating from firebase, first rating always shows up as nan

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to download the ratings from firebase database and then show them on a Mapbox subtitle. however the first and only the first infographic shows up as nan.

Ive tried dispatches and times, and unfortunately nothing seems to be working. I have no clue what to do.

```
func showCarIcon() {

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("location").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            if dict["Activity"] as! String == "Car" {
                let longitude = dict["Longitude"] as! String
                let lattitude = dict["Lattitude"] as! String
                let title = dict["Title"] as! String
                let key = dict["id"] as! String
                self.carIconArray.insert(coordinate(title: title, carLat: lattitude, carLng: longitude, idKey: key), at: 0)
                let n = self.carIconArray.count
                for carMarker in 1...n {

                    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lattitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)

                   let carMarker = CustomPointAnnotation(coordinate: location)

                    var totalrating = Double(0)
                    var ratingcount = Double(0)


                    self.ref.child("location/\(key)/Ratings").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
                        for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {
                            let snap = childSnap as! DataSnapshot
                            let rating = snap.value as! Double
                            totalrating += rating
                            ratingcount += 1

                        }



                        let netRating = Double(totalrating/ratingcount)
                        let final = Double(round(100*netRating)/100)




                        carMarker.reuseIdentifier = "carMarker"
                        carMarker.image = UIImage(named: "carPin")
                        carMarker.title = title
                        carMarker.subtitle = "\(final)/5.0"
                        carMarker.key = key




                            // add Car marke to array
                            self.arrCarMarkers.append(carMarker)

                            // add array to map
                           self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.arrCarMarkers)



                    })

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

JSON Tree

```
 "location" : {
   "-LkKU4hLZQfI2XDdljQk-LkKU9ZkGYnP82pKeZoe-LkKUD50ouEXYT9LuzSw" : {
   "Activity" : "Car",
   "Coordinate" : "-35.13815006034659,138.53838695658027",
   "Description" : "H",
   "Difficulty" : "Medium",
   "Lattitude" : "-35.13815006034659",
   "Longitude" : "138.53838695658027",
   "Ratings" : {
      "WgPMwulBX9ScTHqa0htPyr355TQ2" : 4
      "Bfodb4309gn30fnofjlnd3u93438" : 5
               },
   "Title" : "H",
   "id" : "-LkKUD50ouEXYT9LuzSw",
 }
}
```

Please can someone help me!!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON at `location` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Does the "id" value "-LkKUD50ouEXYT9LuzSw" exist elsewhere in the firebase database?  I'm wondering if it can't find it.

Comment: Thanks @LorenRogers the issue was with the idKey! Thankyou for your help!